# Why doesn't my nested for / do-while loop to sort through an array not output my final prints in C?

Tags: c, sorting, for-loop, arraylist, do-while

Why can't I get this loop to stop? My tracker is an array filled with a random number of elements in the range of 1 to 10. Lets say the size of this array is 50. I want to check all values 1 to 10 are in the array by checking the entry of when the number appears first in the array. I also want to keep track of the biggest value for the entry and store it as numberOfHops and so if all numbers are in the array, the output should be numberOfHops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 int i, k, m, entry = 0, numberOfHops = 0;
 const int L = 10;
 int tracker[50] ={1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 10, 9, 8, 7 , 6 //etc etc//};
 int sitesVisited = 0; 
for (k =1; k<=L; k++ )
    {   do {
        m=0;
        if (k == tracker[m])
        {
            sitesVisited += 1;
            entry = m;
        }
        if (entry > numberOfHops)
        {
            numberOfHops = entry;
        }
        m++;
    } while (sitesVisited < k); 
    }
if (sitesVisited == L) {
    printf("Particle took %d hops to explore environment.\n", numberOfHops);
}
else {
    printf("Particle did not explore entire environment.");
}
}
```

Comment: Evidently, `sitesVisited < k` is always true. That says that `k == tracker[m]` isn't true enough times. You should use a debugger and watch what happens to values along the way to see if it makes sense to you.

Comment: `if (entry > numberOfHops)`... possible undefined behaviour...using unitialized value of a type with trap representation.

Comment: As suggested `entry` is used without a known value.

Comment: @lurker Yes 'sitesVistied < k' should be true until it then becomes equal when the  'k == tracker[i]' condition is met then I want it stop and proceed for the next value of k... am I misunderstanding how this works? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I assume you wrote the code, so I assume you know how you want it to work. It's obviously not working as expected, so using a debugger you can get in there and see what's happening to values in an unexpected way. `entry` is undefined initially (which you should fix) but shouldn't be causing your infinite loop. By the way, your inconsistent indentation makes your code somewhat difficult to read. You might want to fix that, too.

Comment: Thank you, i have edited it so that `int entry = 0`  to start with and then with each iteration of k, it will be replaced given the condition of `k = tracker[i]` being met. I havent used a debugger beofre so will have a loom into that. Thanks

Comment: You can do some simple debugging by printing out the value of `k` and `tracker[m]` each time through the loop, and include a print inside of the `k == tracker[m]` condition. It seems clear that at some value of `k` the values in `tracker` from that point forward are never equal to `k`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `m=0;` line. You should declare it before `do {` cycle start.
Every loop you initialize it with 0 instead of increasing.